# Word for something which isn’t spreading and under control

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What could be the words for a scale/mark on a certain part of the skin which is small and not spreading(on any other part of the body) like the word ‘limited’? Example:
“Your psoriasis mark, it’s ‘confined’(add your suggested word here)”

Comment: What kind of mark? One that appears naturally or one that comes from being hurt by something or someone?? Please provide more context.

Comment: Skin disease, like Psoriasis.

Comment: Edited my example as well.

Comment: patches or plaques: psoriasis is easily found online with these words.

Comment: I mean, asked for a word which means ‘not spreading’. Like: confined. But the word confined won’t be appropriate here because it’s not inside the skin...

Comment: a patch is a lesion. lesions are said to develop (come out) but they themselves do not spread.

Comment: No! I can’t explain it to you! I’m searching for words like ‘controlled’ or ‘restrained’. Like: “The lesion is under control/restrained.”

Comment: halt, prevent, stem, stop, tackle, contain, control, curb, limit, reduce, slow, manage

Answer (score 2):

"Contained" is the expression normally used when a virus or infection has been prevented from spreading among the population (ie from person to person).

Your suggestion of "confined to..." seems perfectly accurate for something visible, such as a rash, which is only one particular area, but I believe the medical term would be **[localised](https://www.seattlechildrens.org/conditions/a-z/rash-or-redness-localized/)**. Localized means the rash occurs on one small part of the body.